# How to get the date of the form submitter or the document in a published add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

In my Google Apps Script add-on *Simply Send*, I try to capture the timestamp. I get timestamp (using `e.response.getTimestamp().toString();`) but it is always formatted for EST, which is my timezone (The timezone of the master script file).

What I would like to have is either the timezone of the person submitting the form, or the timezone of the form document that the add-on is installed on.

If anyone has a cool trick to get this information it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that the user running your add-on is in the same timezone as their form, then getting the user's time zone should be sufficient.

The CalendarApp has a [getTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#gettimezone) method that will return the time zone of the user's primary calendar.

```js
template.timezone = CalendarApp.getTimeZone();
```

Below is a quick Forms Add-on demo that will display that time zone in a dialog. The time zone is returned as a String, with the name of the time zone as listed by [Joda.org](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). This is the format used by Google Apps Script TriggerBuilders, for example:

```js
 // Schedule the trigger to execute at noon every day in the US/Pacific time zone
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(12)
   .everyDays(1)
   .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
   .create();
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Code.gs

```js
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc  Limits the script to only accessing the current form.
 */

var DIALOG_TITLE = 'Timezone probe';

/**
 * Adds a custom menu with items to show the sidebar and dialog.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
      .createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed; calls onOpen() to ensure menu creation and
 * any other initializion work is done immediately.
 *
 * @param {Object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger.
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}


/**
 * Opens a dialog. The dialog structure is described in the Dialog.html
 * project file.
 */
function showDialog() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Dialog');
  template.timezone = CalendarApp.getTimeZone();
  var ui = template
      .evaluate()
      .setWidth(350)
      .setHeight(180)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, DIALOG_TITLE);
}
```

#### Dialog.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      Your timezone is: <?!= timezone ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Downside: You may have users wondering why your add-in needs access to their calendar.

Comment: It would be nice to get the time zone of the current document in all the apps, but I will take what I can get.  Thank you.

Comment: That helps, but now I need to figure out how to take the CalendarApp timezone and merge it with a response timestamp to show the correct time.    Is there a way to get the GMT offset from the calendar app timezone?

Comment: I started down that path, but realized you hadn't said what you wanted to do with the timezone info. I didn't see any existing JavaScript questions about it, but there are a couple in Java. Nothing extreme; build an associative array with the data from Joda, for a simple look-up. There may be a clever way to use the native Date methods. Perhaps take the EST time and use Utilities.formatDate(), which takes a TZ param. It would make an interesting follow up question!

Comment: I have to test before I write as an answer, but this is what I came up with for converting a timestamp to the users timezone.   Thank you Mogsdad for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I still need to test (and I will edit my response if it doesn't work).   This is what I came up with to get the documents timezone from the response.  Thank you Mogsdad for the help.

```
  var timestamp =  thisResponse.getTimestamp();
  var timezone = CalendarApp.getTimeZone();
  var timestampZ = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timezone, "EEE, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
  timestamp = new Date(timestampZ);
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! (I still think it would be better as it's own Q & A, because it's an interesting problem all on its own!)